# .epub book is not showing images on ipad

Tags: image, ipad, xhtml, epub

I want to create a .epub book using images.I have used one image in single xhtml page. But problem is this iPad is not showing images only blue question marke is placed their.

But this book is perfectily working in samsung tab. I have also reduced the image size but the problem is still same.

Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the method(s) you used to create the .epub file? In cases like these it's useful to provide some code

Comment: Have you run epubcheck? Also, what format are the images in?

Comment: The blue question mark indicates that the file cannot be found/accessed. You might want to check the file permissions on the image file and/or the directory in which it is kept. That is something that could differ between ereaders.

Answer (score 0):

I would check case sensitivity.  Some devices don't see "sample.jpg" and "Sample.jpg" as the same file.